# Getting random array from a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a page set up for testimonials for a company website. Just the standard message first name, last name, message, blah blah..anyways I can pull the message up and have a single entry show up however, I would like it to randomly generate a 'testimonial' I know there is random_array functions already included in PHP but how would I go about it in a while loop? Thats the only way really I have learned to pull information from a MySQL database. So if there is a simpler way I am all ears.

```
<?php 
    mysql_select_db("test", $link); 
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM testimonials LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        // var_dump($row['message']); die;
?>                      
    <p>
<?php
    echo $row['message']; ?>"<br/>
    <div id="quote"><?php echo $row['first_name']. " " .$row['last_name'];?></div><div id="location"><?php echo $row['city']. " , " .$row['state'];?></div><br/>

    <div class="readmore">
        <a href="greenInformation.php">Click Here to view more</a>
    </div></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It depends a bit on what you want to achieve. You can use "shuffle" to keep changing your array, or shuffle just once an then access in sequence. What do you want to do if new items are entered? Give them priority? Lots of ways to do this...

Comment: I was hoping there my be a way to just make it ramdom based on the ID in the table. These are not going to be 'real' testimonials these are going to be created and just stored in this static table that will be manually updated if someone has a kind word to say. So I was thinking if there was a way to make it random based off the PK ID it would be easiest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Another, and better method, is if you have a ID column, then you could generate a random number and get a row based on that.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=".mt_rand(1,500);
```

Comment: only use `ORDER BY RAND()` for small data sets

Comment: oh come on! I assumed he wouldn't have like, 1000 testimonials, if this was from a twitter feed I would have done it differently.

Comment: i voted up, agreed i would suspect it was fine, its just worth noteing that it would scale poorly.

Comment: LOL. Def not a Twitter feed...maybe 10 testimonials that might get updated once a month max I would say 50-100

Comment: If it's 10, when not just have a neat animation with javascript to cycle through them?

Comment: David that seem to work perfectly..Could I ask though how does it scale poorly? Does it put a strain on the Database or something?

Comment: If you have say, 500 rows, the database is going through all those values, which is a strain because you're only getting one value and one value only.

Comment: ah, this is a small thing thats sticking towards the bottom of a simple company page no flashy stuff as primarily old people would be the attracted audience

Comment: OK, I understand I'll keep this as a quick and dirty just to be done with it I really don't think very many will be going in here so I should be safe thanks alot David for the quick response!

Comment: i wouldn't change until it was in the tens of  thousands, 500 is not many. Dependent on hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of testimonials increase in a unbelievable way, you can use this:

```
$answer = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `testimonials`");  
$nb = mysql_fetch_row($answer);  
$rand = mt_rand(0,$nb[0] - 1);  
$answer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` LIMIT $rand, 1");
```